# Combine the result of the function on a row in one column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large `data.table` where one column contains text, here is a simple example:

```
x = data.table(text = c("This is the first text", "Second text"))
```

I would like to get a `data.table` with one column containing all the words of all the texts. Here was my try:

```
x[, strsplit(text, " ")]
                     text
1: This is the first text
2:            Second text
```

Which results in:

```
      V1     V2
1:  This Second
2:    is   text
3:   the Second
4: first   text
5:  text Second
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
   text
1: This 
2: is
3: the
4: first
5: text
6: Second
7: text
```

Comment: `splitstackshape::cSplit` with `direction = long` is often used for this task. ([Steady flow of dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+cSplit+long)). Convenient if you also have other columns which needs to be 'expanded' when the focal column is `sep`arated and reshaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close and looking for:

```
data.table(text=unlist(strsplit(x$text, " ")))

#     text
#1:   This
#2:     is
#3:    the
#4:  first
#5:   text
#6: Second
#7:   text
```

Comment: This method is definitely faster than splitting within the data.table frame

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned by @Henrik in the comments, you could use `cSplit` from the `splitstackshape` package for this task:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(x, "text", sep = " ", direction = "long")
```

Which gives:

```
#     text
#1:   This
#2:     is
#3:    the
#4:  first
#5:   text
#6: Second
#7:   text
```

You could also create a column to help identify the initial sentences in the result:

```
x %>% dplyr::mutate(n = 1:n()) %>% cSplit(., "text", " ", "long")
```

Which gives:

```
#     text n
#1:   This 1
#2:     is 1
#3:    the 1
#4:  first 1
#5:   text 1
#6: Second 2
#7:   text 2
```

Comment: I upvoted you as well, especially for nice bonus of adding `n`, but Colonel Beauvel answered first and his implementation uses less memory on my huge data set (10Gb).